# Error: Can't Resolve 'node_modules/marked/lib/marked.js'

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, javascript-marked

I'm trying to compile my Angular app using

```
ng serve
```

The error I receive is

```
Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules/marked/lib/marked.js' in 'C:\ProjectName'
```

The error doesn't tell me what file it is coming from, and only points to the entire project folder.

I can't find any reference in my code to marked.js, it's not in my package.json either, i've searched all files and even tried installing/uninstalling marked.js

I can't find any stacks on this. Is there a way to find out where the source of this error is from?

Comment: Error is because of the node modules itself. Delete node modules and do npm install in your project structure

Comment: Even after deleting the node_modules folder and all it's content this error is persisting.

Comment: Found it, in `angular.json`, there was this reference to `marked.js` in the `scripts` property. This was point to a non-existenting file. Changed it to `marked.esm.js`.